# ASP.NET - Control sizes differ in design and run time

Tags: asp.net, size, controls

I've recently noticed that sometimes control sizes differ from the ones set during design time. For example, I have a dropdownlist placed in a table column. Here's how it looks like in design time:[image: Design time version]

And here's how it looks like in run time:[image: Run time version] What is the reason for this?

P.S. Sorry, I could not figure out how to properly layout images.

Comment: the drop down is empty when you run and with no data it defaults to small size, if you specify fixed size to it, it will show exact size both in design and run time.

Comment: Sometimes dropdown heights get smaller too. I have this kind of problem with all the controls on my form.

Comment: I usually have to set DDL heights to 24px in the CSS. I added link in my answer for tag mapping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in IE; I usually have to compromise on this when setting a width in the CSS. Depending on your situation you could add a meta tag for a more modern version of IE. You might also look at tag mapping; I've heard that you can leverage more control this way but cannot confirm that.

[Fixing ASP.NET Server Control Rendering Issues with Tag Mapping](http://leedumond.com/blog/fixing-asp-net-server-control-rendering-issues-with-tag-mapping/)

Also, make sure you use a fixed (not %) width in the CSS.